# Can't open tortoisehg second times

Tags: macos, tortoisehg

Hi i download tortoisehg but I can open it only once. When I try open tortoisehg second times a have alert TortoiseHg error and in console exited with code 255

i have 10.9 osx version
thanks for help

Comment: Hi, I experience the same problem. I have created a bug report, it is available at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3604/ Hopefully the guys will post back here once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - as of TortoiseHG version 3.1.0 the bug seems to be fixed:
 https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-3.1.0-mac-x64.zip

---

For older versions - this can be worked around by disabling the argv emulation as described in [this answer](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3437/tortoise-hg-crashes-when-opened-from#comment-7923227).